# Property alias (as arguably the most elegant solution for Identifiable)

Tags: swift, protocols

What if I want to conform to a protocol and the protocol defines a property name which I don't like?
For example:

```
struct Currency: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let rate: Double
}
```

But in this case it would be great to have a more meaningful name for "id" property. So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
struct Currency: Identifiable {
    propertyalias iso = id
    let iso: String
    let rate: Double
}
```

Comment: Your best bet may be to wrap `id` in a computed property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "property alias".

However, you can wrap the property in a computed property that you can name as you see fit.

```
struct Currency: Identifiable {
    let iso: String
    let rate: Double

    var id: String { 
        iso
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Swift 5.2+
Inspired by [How Swift keypaths let us write more natural code](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/57/how-swift-keypaths-let-us-write-more-natural-code)

```
protocol MyIdentifiable: Identifiable {
    associatedtype ID
    static var idKey: KeyPath<Self, ID> { get }
}

extension MyIdentifiable {
    var id: ID {
        self[keyPath: Self.idKey]
    }
}

struct Currency: MyIdentifiable {
    static let idKey = \Self.iso
    let iso: String
    let rate: Double
}
```